# How does KSQL restore streams and their persistent queries?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Internally I can see it has a topic _confluent-ksql-_command_topic that has every command that I have run, but it is still not completely clear how KSQL restores the state of which persistent queries are running.

Comment: What do you mean by state? The ksql server consumes the command topic, and (re)starts the topologies

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am not sure if this is a misconfiguration issue on our side.
We noticed in production the persistent queries that write in some streams had just disappeared for no particular reason.
When restarting ksqldb the streams were there, but the queries were missing and also their consumers. Also in the _command topic everything was there.

Comment: Without seeing your server config or logs, that'd be hard to answer